# Can't reach stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, 408-timeout

From my home, I can't open Stackoverflow.com.  Here's a tracert:

```
  7     7 ms    11 ms     7 ms  te2-1.ccr01.ams05.atlas.cogentco.com [149.6.129.13]
  8    10 ms     7 ms     7 ms  te1-4.mpd03.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.0.85]
  9     7 ms    11 ms     7 ms  te9-2.3494.ccr02.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.48.241]
 10    92 ms    91 ms    92 ms  te3-2.ccr02.ymq02.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.0.69]
 11   116 ms   115 ms   115 ms  te8-7.ccr01.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.28.1]
 12   127 ms   139 ms   127 ms  te0-0-0-3.ccr21.mci01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.2.217]
 13   140 ms   139 ms   135 ms  te4-4.mpd02.den01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.7.130]
 14   160 ms   159 ms   159 ms  te7-3.ccr01.smf01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.3.14]
 15   174 ms   171 ms   171 ms  te4-1.ccr01.pdx01.atlas.cogentco.com [66.28.4.94]
 16   180 ms   172 ms   175 ms  38.104.104.98
 17   172 ms   179 ms   263 ms  ptldorpbcr01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.209]
 18   180 ms   182 ms   179 ms  vl16-eugnor53cr01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.190]
 19   189 ms   195 ms   194 ms  206-192-226-18.lsnetworks.net [206.192.226.18] 
 20   178 ms   180 ms   182 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 21   176 ms   184 ms   180 ms  vlan5-cvo-colo2.peak.org [69.59.218.226]
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

From work, I can reach Stackoverflow.com, with a tracert ending in:

```
 18   180 ms   178 ms   182 ms  206-192-226-18.lsnetworks.net [206.192.226.18]
 19   180 ms   179 ms   181 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 20   178 ms   182 ms   177 ms  vlan5-cvo-colo2.peak.org [69.59.218.226]
 21   179 ms   178 ms   177 ms  stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.211]
```

The strange thing is that the home trace almost gets to Stackoverflow.com, but can't quite reach it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your IP is being blocked by SO due to some suspected voting irregularities or overuse: see this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/script-responsibly/).  If I were you, I'd email the SO team (team@stackoverflow.com) with this data and see if they can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've mailed the SO team.  Kinda curious!  I've not been very active the last few weeks, and don't run scripts or scrapers.

Comment: Turns out I was blocked for excessive traffic for setting Opera to refresh every minute.  I had no idea this was excessive (RSS readers must be doing much more?)  So far the block is still in place

Answer (score 0):

> Can’t reach stackoverflow.com

Trying stretching your fingertips bit further - it's probably just *barely* out of reach.  Maybe a little yoga?

If that doesn't help then I'm afraid your only choice is to move closer to it.

Good luck!

Comment: I am tempted to upvote due to hilarity; I am tempted to downvote due to not an useful answer. So I suppose I will do neither. :)

Comment: <*cough*> Comment <*cough*>  Excuse me...